# Preserve Color In GeoBackground

Tags: plotting, geographics, background

When you use a `ReliefPlot` as a `GeoBackground`, it seems to change the underlying colour scheme. Is it possible to preserve the original colour scheme?

```
data = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/hailey.dem.gz", "Data"]
steps[z_] :=
  Which[
   z <= 1000, Return[White],
   1000 < z <= 1500, Return[RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.5]],
   1500 < z <= 2000, Return[RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 0.5]],
   2000 < z <= 2500, Return[RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.5]],
   2000 < z, Return[RGBColor[1, 1, 1, 0.5]]
   ];

background = 
 ReliefPlot[data, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> steps]
```

[image]

Now, when you use it in `GeoGraphics[]`, strange things happen (ignore the aspect ratio etc, I'm just interested that the colours change!)

```
(* both give same result *) 
GeoGraphics[, GeoBackground -> background]
GeoGraphics[, GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[background]]
```

[image]

---

If you change RGB colour values to predefined colours, it works fine.

```
steps2[z_] :=
  Which[
   z <= 1000, Return[White],
   1000 < z <= 1500, Return[Blue],
   1500 < z <= 2000, Return[Green],
   2000 < z <= 2500, Return[Red],
   2000 < z, Return[Red]
   ];

background = 
 ReliefPlot[data, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> steps2]
GeoGraphics[, GeoBackground -> background]
```

[image]

But I still don't understand why RGB is not allowed?

**Edit** - CMYKColours are allowed.

**Edit** - It seems that the issue only arises if **opacity is included**.

Comment: try  `background =  Rasterize @   ReliefPlot[data, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> steps]`?

Comment: Works - but, @kglr, works as you'd expect but this seems like a bug - should I report?

Comment: it does look like a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly does look like a bug.

```
background = ReliefPlot[data, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> steps, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 300];

gg0 = GeoGraphics[, GeoBackground -> background, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

#### Work-arounds:

Simplest work-around is to use `Image@background` or `Rasterize@background` as option values for `GeoBackground`:

```
gg1 = GeoGraphics[, GeoBackground -> Image@background, ImageSize -> 300];

gg2 = GeoGraphics[, GeoBackground -> Rasterize@background,ImageSize -> 300];
```

Alternatively, we can post-process the output `gg0` to replace the texture image with a correct one:

```
gg3 = ReplaceAll[_Image -> background] @ gg0;

gg4 = ReplaceAll[a_Image :> ColorCombine[ColorSeparate @ a, "RGB"]] @ gg0;

gg5 = ReplaceAll[a_Image :> Image[ImageData@a, "ColorSpace" -> "RGB"]] @ gg0;
```

All five work-arounds give the same result:

```
Grid @ Partition[#, 3] & @ Map[Labeled[ToExpression @ #, #, Top] &] @
 {"gg0", "gg1", "gg2", "gg3", "gg4", "gg5"}
```

[image]

#### A possible culprit:

The function `` GeoGraphics`GraphicsToImage `` is called at some stage by `GeoGraphics` to construct background texture. Used with `background` as the first argument it gives

```
GeoGraphics`GraphicsToImage[background, 300]
```

[image]

which matches the texture image in `gg0`:

```
Show[First @ Cases[gg0, Texture[t_] :> t, All], ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]